# How to call method of the controller to the view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In controller

```
def test
  command = 'pwd'
  result = `#{command}`

   respond_to do |format| 
     format.html { redirect_to(users_url) } 
     format.js { render :text => "$('#teste').html('#{result}');" } 
   end 
end
```

I want to show the variable result

In view

```
<%= link_to 'Testar', test_users_path, :method => :get, :remote => true  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a helper_method.

In your controlller:

```
private
def test
  ...
end
helper_method :test

In your view:

<% test -%>
```

Comment: I want to show the return only after clicking a button.